# javascript code is not wordking properly in WordPress loop

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I used this http://jsfiddle.net/cburgmer/NfE3c/166/ example in a wordpress loop. But the code is working for once only. I want to make this code working for all posts in the page given below.

Here is the page link where I am working http://corey.bluwebz.com/find-a-business-card/

Full code is given below

```
<?php 
/* Template Name: Blog page
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="content" class="home clearfix">
<div id="inner-content" class="wrap cf">
<?php query_posts('post_type=post&post_status=publish&posts_per_page=3&paged='. get_query_var('paged')); ?>

    <?php if( have_posts() ): ?>

        <?php while( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>

        <main id="main" class="m-all t-2of3 d-5of7 cf" role="main" itemscope itemprop="mainContentOfPage" itemtype="http://schema.org/Blog">

        <article id="post-<?php get_the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( array(200,220) ); ?></a>
<header class="article-header">
<h1 class="page-title" itemprop="headline"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>

<p class="byline vcard">
<?php printf( __( 'Posted', 'bonestheme').' <time class="updated" datetime="%1$s" itemprop="datePublished">%2$s</time> '.__( 'by',  'bonestheme').' <span class="author">%3$s</span>', get_the_time('Y-m-j'), get_the_time(get_option('date_format')), get_the_author_link( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) )); ?>
</p>
</header> <?php // end article header ?>
<section class="entry-content cf" itemprop="articleBody">
<div class="bsnscontent">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
<!-- custom field -->
<?php 

                    $phn_num = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'phone_number' );
                    $address = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'address' );
                    $email = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'email' );
                    $web_site = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'web_site' );
                    if($address)
                    {
                        echo "<br> Address: ".$address[0];
                    }
                    echo "<br> Phone Number: ".$phn_num[0];
                    echo "<br> Email: ".$email[0];
                    echo "<br> Website: ".$web_site[0];
?></div><?php

                    $images = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'business_card' );

if ( $images ) {
    foreach ( $images as $attachment_id ) {
        $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'large' );
        $full_size = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id );

        printf( '<div class="bsnscard"><a href="%s">%s</a></div>', $full_size, $thumb );
}
}
if ( !$images ) {
        ?>
<!-- HTML TO CANVAS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cburgmer.github.com/rasterizeHTML.js/rasterizeHTML.allinone.js"></script>

<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="200" style="border: 1px solid black;background:#EEEEEE;"></canvas>

<div id="thehtml" style="display: none;">
    <style>
        .test {
          font-size: 20px;
     }
    </style>
    <div class="test"><?php if($address)
                    {
                        echo "<br> Address: ".$address[0];
                    }
                    echo "<br> Phone Number: ".$phn_num[0];
                    echo "<br> Email: ".$email[0];
                    echo "<br> Website: ".$web_site[0]; ?></div>
</div>
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    context = canvas.getContext('2d'),

    html_container = document.getElementById("thehtml"),
    html = html_container.innerHTML;

rasterizeHTML.drawHTML(html).then(function (renderResult) {
    context.drawImage(renderResult.image, 10, 25);
});


</script>
<!-- HTML TO CANVAS -->
<?php } ?>  
<!-- custom field -->
<!-- /#post-<?php get_the_ID(); ?> -->
</section>

        <footer class="article-footer cf">
                                    <p class="footer-comment-count">
                                        <?php comments_number( __( '<span>No</span> Comments', 'bonestheme' ), __( '<span>One</span> Comment', 'bonestheme' ), __( '<span>%</span> Comments', 'bonestheme' ) );?>
                                    </p>
<?php printf( '<p class="footer-category">' . __('filed under', 'bonestheme' ) . ': %1$s</p>' , get_the_category_list(', ') ); ?>

                  <?php the_tags( '<p class="footer-tags tags"><span class="tags-title">' . __( 'Tags:', 'bonestheme' ) . '</span> ', ', ', '</p>' ); ?>

</footer>
</article>
</main>
<?php endwhile; ?>
        <div class="navigation clearfix">
            <span class="newer"><?php previous_posts_link(__('« Newer','bonestheme')) ?></span> <span class="older"><?php next_posts_link(__('Older »','bonestheme')) ?></span>
        </div><!-- /.navigation -->

    <?php else: ?>

        <div id="post-404" class="noposts">

            <p><?php _e('None found.','bonestheme'); ?></p>

        </div><!-- /#post-404 -->

    <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>

            </div> <!-- inner content -->
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: What is the `the_post()` function ?

Comment: debug  with `var_dump($images);` because I suspect it has 1 element tops

Answer (score 0):

`id="canvas"` there might be your problem. If you have multiple canvas elements you will need mutiple unique identifiers to address them. So add an index, or something.

Also you should call the rasterize code via https:
https://cburgmer.github.io/rasterizeHTML.js/rasterizeHTML.allinone.js

Last but not least:

You get a 404 for your bootstrap request:
http://corey.bluwebz.com/wp-content/themes/eddiemachado-bones-9db85e4/js/bootstrap.min.js